# Spring Framework role based method security not working in Apache CXF webservice

Tags: spring-security, authorization, cxf

I have a simple Apache CXF webservice with the following beans.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:ssec="http://cxf.apache.org/spring-security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd   
    http://cxf.apache.org/spring-security 
    http://cxf-spring-security.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cxf-spring-security/src/main/resources/schemas/spring-security.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <beans:import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

    <http auto-config='true' >
        <http-basic/>
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>                
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="methodSecurityInterceptor"
          class="org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor">            

          <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>                      
          <beans:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager"/>                                          
          <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <beans:value>
                org.mycompany.com.CxfSpringSecuredService.HelloWorldImpl.sayHi=ROLE_OPERATOR
                org.mycompany.com.CxfSpringSecuredService.HelloWorldImpl.sayHiAdmin*=ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR
                org.mycompany.com.CxfSpringSecuredService.HelloWorldImpl.deleteAccounts*=ROLE_SUPERVISOR
            </beans:value>
          </beans:property>                                                 
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
       <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
          <beans:list>
              <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />                          
          </beans:list>
       </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>          
                <user name="operator" password="operator" authorities="ROLE_OPERATOR" />
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="sup" password="sup" authorities="ROLE_SUPERVISOR" />                  
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>       


    <jaxws:endpoint 
      id="helloWorld" 
      implementor="org.mycompany.com.CxfSpringSecuredService.HelloWorldImpl" 
      address="/HelloWorld" />  

</beans:beans>
```

My webservice implementation is the following three simple methods:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "org.mycompany.com.CxfSpringSecuredService.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    public String sayHi(String text) {          

        SecurityContext context =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        if (context != null){
            Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
            if (authentication != null){
                Collection<GrantedAuthority> roles = authentication.getAuthorities();

                if (roles != null){  
                    GrantedAuthority[] authorities = new GrantedAuthority[roles.size()];
                    roles.toArray(authorities);                 
                    for (int i = 0; i < authorities.length; i++)                    
                        text = text + " " + authorities[i];
                }
            }
        }               


        return "Hello " + text;
    }

    public String sayHiAdmin(){    

        return "Hello admin";
    }

    public String deleteAccounts(String name){
        return "Accounts deleted by " + name;
    }
}
```

I have a C# client that calls the web service and passes authentication information within the SOAP header.  I know that my client is passing authentication information as I get the following message in an exception:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="Spring Security Application"'.
```

if I issue invalid credentials.  I issue proper credentials I get the correct response for each web service call.  So far, so good.

If I pass credential information for operator, and call method deleteAccounts, I expected the same authorized error as above, but webservice method is invoked correctly.

I have looked through the docs here [Spring Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#authz-arch) but cannot determine what may be missing.

Any ideas?

TIA.

**Edit:  Corrected user config.**

Comment: Side note: at least one of `context` and `authentication` will never be `null`, possibly both. IIRC, SpringSec guarantees some things that make it much less necessary to code so defensively.

Comment: Thanks for side note.  I did this because execution will hang when attempting to get granted authorities.